# Can anyone help me with this jQuery infield label for text inputs

Tags: jquery

So here's my scenario, I need to have an inputs name and ID equal two different things but the code below only allows the effect to work if label, id, and name all have the same value, for example the following code works fine:

```
        <p>
            <label for="eventid" class="label_login">*Participant Code</label><br />
            <input type="text" name="eventid" value="" id="eventid" class="input_size"/>    
        </p>
```

When I change it to how I need it to be it completely stops working

Example of how I need it to be:

```
        <p>
            <label for="eventid" class="label_login">*Participant Code</label><br />
            <input type="text" name="eventid" value="" id="part_code" class="input_size"/>  
        </p>
```

Can anyone tell me where in the jQuery script below does it state that name, label, and ID all have to match? and how can I remove either name or ID from that requirement. Thank you in advance.

[Non-minified version](https://github.com/dcneiner/In-Field-Labels-jQuery-Plugin/blob/master/src/jquery.infieldlabel.js)

```
(function($){$.InFieldLabels=function(b,c,d){var f=this;f.$label=$(b);f.label=b;f.$field=$(c);f.field=c;f.$label.data("InFieldLabels",f);f.showing=true;f.init=function(){f.options=$.extend({},$.InFieldLabels.defaultOptions,d);if(f.$field.val()!=""){f.$label.hide();f.showing=false};f.$field.focus(function(){f.fadeOnFocus()}).blur(function(){f.checkForEmpty(true)}).bind('keydown.infieldlabel',function(e){f.hideOnChange(e)}).change(function(e){f.checkForEmpty()}).bind('onPropertyChange',function(){f.checkForEmpty()})};f.fadeOnFocus=function(){if(f.showing){f.setOpacity(f.options.fadeOpacity)}};f.setOpacity=function(a){f.$label.stop().animate({opacity:a},f.options.fadeDuration);f.showing=(a>0.0)};f.checkForEmpty=function(a){if(f.$field.val()==""){f.prepForShow();f.setOpacity(a?1.0:f.options.fadeOpacity)}else{f.setOpacity(0.0)}};f.prepForShow=function(e){if(!f.showing){f.$label.css({opacity:0.0}).show();f.$field.bind('keydown.infieldlabel',function(e){f.hideOnChange(e)})}};f.hideOnChange=function(e){if((e.keyCode==16)||(e.keyCode==9))return;if(f.showing){f.$label.hide();f.showing=false};f.$field.unbind('keydown.infieldlabel')};f.init()};$.InFieldLabels.defaultOptions={fadeOpacity:0.5,fadeDuration:300};$.fn.inFieldLabels=function(c){return this.each(function(){var a=$(this).attr('for');if(!a)return;var b=$("input#"+a+"[type='text'],"+"input#"+a+"[type='password'],"+"textarea#"+a);if(b.length==0)return;(new $.InFieldLabels(this,b[0],c))})}})(jQuery);
```

Comment: The plugin code you supply is a minified version of a 130-line javascript file.  That's not really usable for anyone who wants to help.  (I added a link to the full source code.)

Comment: By the way this is where I found the example in which I took it from, hope this helps.   http://fuelyourcoding.com/scripts/infield/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, this isn't an issue with the plugin.  The specification of `label for="id"` is that the label should use the element id as its `for` attribute.  In your "how I need it to be" attribute, you're using the name as the `for` attribute.  Not going to work.  The name shouldn't need to match the id, but the element id you put in "for" has to match the element's id attribute.

Comment: I feel kinda dumb now after spending some times scratching my head lol  Thanks Jacob

Comment: @NewB "feel kinda dumb" is a periodical state in this industry that all who participate encounter :)

Answer (score 0):

Can't you just rename/id the properties with that plugin?

```
    <p>
        <label for="part_code" class="label_login">*Participant Code</label><br />
        <input type="text" name="part_code" value="" id="part_code" class="input_size"/>  
    </p>
```

Unless you need the `name` and `id` properties to be different for that input...if that is the case can you please explain why/what you are trying to accomplish with it?